# Cannot get Type declared in a .NET Framework assembly from a .NET Core 2 assembly

Tags: c#, types, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2 console app which is performing some maintenance/upgrade work on the DB underlying a ASP.NET website running  on .NET Framework 4.7.1.

The console app needs to read in the assembly-qualified type names of classes which are declared in the .NET Framework assemblies. It does this using `Type.GetType("[assembly-qualified name]";`

This code works perfectly well for the built-in .NET types but it throws an exception when it comes to types defined in our own assemblies. Confusingly, I can declare a variable of one of these types in the .NET Core console app but I'm unable to instantiate a `Type` object referencing the same type.

For example, this works...

```
var cs = Common.CustomerManagement.Person.CustomerStatus.ApprovedCustomer;
```

but this...

```
var ct = Type.GetType("Common.CustomerManagement.Person+CustomerStatus, Common, Version=1.0.6793.16016, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null;");
```

...throws the exception...

> System.IO.FileLoadException: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>      at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepalive)
>      at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
>      at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Type.GetType(String typeName)

I realise that in the code which works I'm referencing an enum *on* the type and in the code which doesn't work I'm referencing just the type, but the working code shows that the referenced .NET Framework assembly *can* be loaded whereas the non-working code suggests that the type is not available to the .NET Core console app.

Comment: It is not happy about the assembly name you provided.  "1.0.6793.16016" is a *very* ugly version number, never let the build system auto-increment the [AssemblyVersion] when you need to make reflection work.  You'll inevitably get that number wrong in your code.  Odd problem to have in a .netcore project btw, I'd have to guess you are hoofing this yourself instead of using Project > Properties > Package in Visual Studio.

Comment: You're right - I found that once I removed the version number from the assembly-qualified name it was accepted.

Comment: @HansPassant - If you change your comment to a suggested answer then I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I just have no idea where that fugly version number came from.  Tell us about it in your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the type name is the `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName` which includes a version number.

It's the version number which was causing the problem. Once I removed the version number and left the other information in the type name, it worked.